# iTunes sort tracks in ascending order 

Tags: itunes

[image]

See how it tracks are listed out of order? 2, 1, 3, 4? I want iTunes to sort the tracks in ascending order but I don't know how to make iTunes do this.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Sort by Track index]

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the "track number" column as explained in another answer, it will just change the order in which the tracks are **displayed** in iTunes; if you have problem with the order in which they are **played**, you should also check that all tracks have the same "Album Artists".

I found the trick [here](http://godkillzyou.wordpress.com/2009/04/17/itunes-doesnt-sort-by-track-number-fixed/), and it solved the ordering issue I had on my iPod.